# How to Manipulate the Text element in Html by A Variable whose value is given by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to Manipulate the Text with id 'varname' (Spartans) with the value inputted in the form saved as a variable 'input'

```
<div class="middle">
    <h2 class="greet" id="demo">Welcome Back,&nbsp; <span id="varname">Spartan</span></h2>
     <div class="form">
    <form>
        <label for="Name">Enter Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="Name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            var input= document.getElementById("Name").value;
            document.getElementById("varname").innerHTML = input;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<input type="button">` instead of `<input type="submit">`

https://jsfiddle.net/yt0kgnqe/

Comment: How to Make the form to be submitted when Enter key is pressed? Now The form is only submitted when button is clicked

Comment: @Aadhil Anwar
You could submit the form in the function ```myFunction()``` See here how to do it: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Answer (score 1):

In your form, try this:

```
<form id="manipulate">
    <label for="Name">Enter Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="Name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your javascript,

```
document.getElementById("manipulate").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData(e.target)

    document.getElementById('varname').innerHTML = formData.get("Name")
})
```

`e.preventDefault()` stops the form from reloading the page when submitting so that I have time to insert data from form to the UI